# Dynamically handle the background and foreground colors inside UICollectionViewCell's elements

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` which contains a `UIView` enclosing a `UILabel`. I have to change the background color of `UIView` and the text color of `UILabel` on the base of a boolean value. The colors on the base of the boolean value work find unless I add the fourth item in the `UICollectionView`. All items from all previous and current cells get the same respective color like that of the items of the fourth cell as soon as I add the fourth item.

The problem is exactly related to 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600351/strange-behaviour-on-adding-constraints-based-upon-condition) but here I cannot add the colors in the `init` method of `UICollectionViewCell` and then activate/deactivate them in `cellForRowAt` on the basis of the boolean value. What could I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the `colors` of `UIView` and `UILabel` in `prepareForReuse()` method of your custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

**Example:**

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        //reset the colors here.........
        customView.backgroundColor = .white
        label.textColor = .black
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't worked completely. Now, it assigns the white background and black text color to the respective items of the first cell (i-e resets the items of the first cell) as soon as I add the second cell. However, it works as expected for the cells being added after the second one (i-e does not reset the items of the previously added cells).

Comment: You need to change the colours while configuring each cell. `prepareForReuse()` will be call every time a cell is reused.

Comment: oh, hahaha...that totally makes sense :D Thank you very much :)